# Get server response after ajax post submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How do i pass my server side validation to my ajax post methods?, I am trying to get the server http response from the server and based on that thrown success/error messages on the client, current php code is:

```
$error = 0;

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if ($condition) {
        //error code
        $error = 0;
      } elseif ($othercondition) {
        //success code
        $error = 1;
      } else {
        //error code
        $error = 0;
      }
    }
```

and my ajax post looks like

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,         
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            console.log("success " + response);
            //if (condition) {
              //# code...
            //} else {
              //# code...
            //}
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
            console.log("error " + response);
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
```

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track. Are you having problems with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server needs to do:

```
echo $error;
```

Whatever the PHP script outputs will be in `response` in the Javascript.

If you want more details, you can use JSON, e.g.

```
echo json_encode(array('error' => $error, 'message' => $message_string));
```

Then in the `$.ajax` options specify

```
dataType: 'json',
```

`response` will then be a Javascript object; `response.error` will be the error value, `response.message` will be the string.